# NGINX Logging on AWS with ec2-user is not happening

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

Below is my edited nginx.conf

```
user ec2-user;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 2048;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    #tcp_nopush          on;
    #tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

}
```

When I changed the user variable from nginx user to ec2-user, the logs are not getting captured in the `/var/log/nginx/access.log` file even though the file is present it always remains zero size

Comment: did you test the nginx.conf if it throw any error ?

Comment: no nginx -t is not throwing any errors, thinking there are some error with ec2-user permissions.